# Argument to pool function in multiprocessing module in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

In the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process) for the `multiprocessing` module the very first example is about the `Pool` command.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

This script is used to demonstrate how the `Pool` method can be used to run the same function in parallel for a series of possible arguments.

They do not, however explain or provide the arguments to the `Pool` method, which in this case equals `5`.

What is that argument? Why is it `5` in this case? Does it have something to do with the number of allowed processes at a given time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the documentation of `Pool`, you are reading just a simple example.

The real documentation of `Pool` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool), where the meaning of the number is clearly explained:

> processes is the number of worker processes to use. If processes is None then the number returned by os.cpu_count() is used.

Comment: I suspected there had to be more information out there. Thanks